# How to Play Youtube video in silverlight3.0

Tags: silverlight-3.0

I am developing a silverlight application in which i want to play youtube video. 
Any Suggestions plz. Any samples or any links for this to refer.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

here's an intersting thread about this issue, with some samples in SL 3.0 beta:

http://silverlight.net/forums/t/53008.aspx

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

They have given this below link as url for the video.

http://www.youtube.com/get_video?video_id=8-_9n5DtKOc&t=vjVQa1PpcFM7S-x5VpWRuwzAo5atG-Cn2Thbe-KaQgo=&fmt=18

But if entered this we are getting AG_E_NETWORK ERROR(4001)

Answer (score 0):

http://slyi.silverlight.googlepages.com/youtube2.html

was working. Now the link used is wrong, but if you change it that example still works!